# How to get data from ajax for modal(popup of bootstrap) blade in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

I have a modal(popup of bootstrap) include a table. Now, when I call ajax and get response successfull, i want get this response to the popup and show it in table, everything that right but my image not show, what is wrong?

Ajax:

```
function detailOrder($id){
    var url= "{{ URL::to('admin/detail_order')}}"+"/"+$id;
    $.ajax({
        type:"get",
        url:url,
        data:"",
        success:function(response){
            console.log(response);
            $('#order').modal('show');
            var trHTML = '';
            $.each(response, function (i, detail_orders) {
                for (i = 0; i < response.order[0].detail_orders.length; i++) {
                    for(j = 0;j<response.order[0].detail_orders[i].product.length;j++){
                        trHTML +=
                        '<tr><td>'
                        +'<img class="table_image" id="pic">'
                        + '</td><td>'
                        + response.order[0].detail_orders[i].product[j].product_name
                        + '</td><td>'
                        + response.order[0].detail_orders[i].quantity 
                        + '</td><td>'
                        + response.order[0].detail_orders[i].product[j].price
                        + '</td><td>'
                        + response.order[0].detail_orders[i].total_amount
                        + '</td></tr>';
                        $("#pic").attr("src","{{ URL::to('admin/storage')}}"+"/"+response.order[0].detail_orders[i].product[j].product_image); 
                    }
                    $('#tBody').append(trHTML);
                }
            });
        },
        error:function(){
            console.log("fail");
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: You should loop over the responses in your ajax success function and add them to the tbody of your table. after that, show the modal

Comment: Hi @Jerodev i updated my ajax, but image not show, I don't know what wrong in that.

Comment: Your image has no src attribute, so there is no image to show

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
success:function(response){
   var html = ''; //initialize your html
   for(i=0;i<response.length;i++) //loop depends on the length of response
   {
      html+= //concatinate the html data in this variable
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>'+response[i].id+'</td>'+
        '</tr>';
   }
   $('#tBody').html(html); //pass the html data to your body
}
```

Comment: but you got the other data?

Comment: check the path of your image

Comment: I have array item and i want show it in table with image, name...I don't know what wrong, if array have from two items to on ,it show first item, another item not show. if array have one item, it not show

Comment: I dunno why you have each function and 2 for loops? Did you based on my example?

Comment: Yes, i have array order_detail, in every object order_detail  have array product, so i have 2 loops

Comment: Why not query them at once? if they are related to each other. Its more easier.

Comment: I will try you idea, but how to solve the image not show? May be i call jquery wrong because all item have id="pic"?

Comment: Have solution add respone in src if don't use jquery? It like:
`trHTML +='<tr><td>'
+'<img class="table_image" id="pic" src='"{{ URL::to('admin/storage')}}"+"/"+response.order[0].detail_orders[i].product[j].product_image '></td><tr>'`

Comment: or you are not targeting the image on the right path. try to query them at once. much more fast and easy

Comment: Do you have a way put variable javascript to src of image?I have a variable img_path and want put it to src of image

Comment: $('#image').attr("src",base_url +'/'+ result.image.name);  in codeigniter I just do like this. I didn't try yet in Laravel.  But try to query your sql at once as advice to make it more cleaner.

Comment: Thanks @Genina Anne Gabuten, i will try the way put them at once

Comment: Accept my answer if it helps you :) Welcome.